# How to open a folder in new Finder window (OSX)

Tags: macos, finder

When navigated deep into a folder tree in OSX Finder, is there a way to select a particular folder and open it in a new instance of Finder?

This is done easily in Windows Explorer -- simply right click the directory and select "Explorer".

There are many reasons one might want to do this.  For example, manually comparing two nearby directory trees.

I'm on OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I assume by "open it in a new instance of Finder", you mean open the location in another Finder window (there is only one instance of the Finder application).

There are a couple ways.

With a folder selected, press Control-Command-O to open it in a new window. This corresponds to the `File > Open in New Window` command. (I recommend just selecting the File menu in the Finder, and experiment by pressing various modifier keys (Shift, Control, Option, and Command) to see all of the different variations of commands). There is also `File > Open in New Window and Close`, which is Command-Option-O, but that's likely not what you want in this particular situation.

You can also go to `View > Show Path Bar` to make sure the path bar is shown at the bottom of the Finder window. Then right-click on one of the folders in the hierarchy and choose `Open Enclosing Folder`.

You can also turn on the option to "Always open folders in a new window" in Finder preferences, and then double-click on a folder to open it in a new window.

Comment: Control-Command-O it is!  Perfect.

Comment: You can also hold down the command key when double-clicking the folder.

Comment: Yup, forgot about that one...

Answer (score 1):

For those here after the last 2012 post, MacOS 10.11 (El Capitan) and 10.12 (Sierra), <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, now has a different effect. It opens a new Finder window with the selected directory, but closes the one you just came from, leaving a single window open. A <kbd>Command</kbd>+Double-Click on a focused directory will open that directory in new tab in the current Finder window, not a new Finder window as the OP was looking for.

But, that said, there are now options which are in the same vein as NSGod's answer for newer MacOS's. In the area “System Preferences” → “Keyboard” → “Shortcuts” → “Services” you can assign your own keyboard shortcuts.

To answer the OP's question in MacOS versions circa 2016-17, go to the area mentioned above. Look for the “Files and Folders” item in the list on the right and expand it if needed. Look for “Open” in the list and click in the rightmost column where you will see a light gray “none”. You can now input your own key assignment as you like. I set mine to “Option-Command-W” (nice easy left hand mashable key combination) for the Open command which will now open a selected focused folder in a new Finder window and still leave the previous Finder window open.